# Android Get Default Animator Duration Scale (Developer's Options)

Tags: android, android-animation

So in my app I really need the animator scale to be set to 1 for things to work properly, and I have tried using this call to get the defined value so I can warn the users about it:

```
val durationScale = Settings.Global.getFloat(contentResolver, Settings.Global.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE, defaultValue = 1f)
```

The weird thing is that on one of my devices (Lenovo Tab M10) has all of the duration scales set to 0.5 as the original values (and this is exactly why I need this to work, some devices come like that from the factory), and then this function does not return the correct value for `ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE`. It always returns the default value sent, 1f in this case, even though it is set to 0.5f. What I have noticed:

1- After manually changing 0.5f from the developer's option to any other value (and even back to 0.5f), the function started returning the correct value.

2- `TRANSITION_ANIMATION_SCALE` and `WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE` are also set to 0.5f as the original values on this device, and even without changing them the function above returns them correctly, except `TRANSITION_ANIMATION_SCALE`, which is the one I need.

Could this be a problem that only happens on this device? It's hard to test because it's the only device I have that has the original values set to 0.5f, but it is extremely frustrating that I am not getting the  original values as I should.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it is frustrating to not get the correct values. I am in a similar situation. I don't know if it will help but I can share my experiences with it.

In some of the devices, the animator duration scale is set to 1x (1.0f) and the default value in the code is set to 0.0f as shown below

```
val durationScale = Settings.Global.getFloat(
   contentResolver, 
   Settings.Global.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE, 
   defaultValue = 0.0f
)
```

But whenever I retrieve the value, it's always 0.0 even though it should return 1.0. And just like you, after manually changing 1x from the developer's option to any other value (and even back to 1x), the function returns the correct value.

Also, this happens in many devices not just one. For example: Pixel, Samsung, etc.